# Sql query to find value of key in json array which contains given string

Tags: java, sql, arrays, json, postgresql

column name "note" - json type

data in one cell of the column is written in the following way :-

```json
[
 {"text":"bbb","userID":"U001","time":16704,"showInReport":true},  
 {"text":"bb","userID":"U001","time":167047,"showInReport":true}
]
```

[interval note column containing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VMhg.png)

how to find value of key text which contains 'bb'
which postgersql query can be used to find results

I used below query which works but if someone gives value as userid or text then it shows wrong result

I'm using Postgres 10.20 version

```
select distinct(workflowid) 
from cyto_records r 
  join cyto_record_results rr on (r.recordid = rr.recordid) 
where rr.interval_note::text LIKE '%aaa%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using JSON_EXTRACT

```
SELECT A.* FROM (    
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(note, '$.text') as val FROM cyto_records) A
WHERE A.val = 'bb'
```

ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-paths

Comment: I don't want exact value but I want value which contains bb means can be any value like bbb, bbbb, abbc etc.

Comment: ERROR:  function json_extract(json, unknown) does not exist
LINE 2: SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(interval_note, '$.text') as val FROM cyt...
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 30

Comment: what is your mysql version? as verion 5.7+ supports json functions

Comment: also, as you did in your query you can use like instaead of equal comparision operator in A.val = will be A.LIKE

Comment: Postgres has no `json_extract` function. But even in MySQL this wouldn't work, as the top level of the JSON value is an array and `JSON_EXTRACT(note, '$.text')` won't iterate over the array and will simply return `null`

Answer (score 0):

For Postgres versions 11 and older, you need to iterate over the array elements:

```
select distinct r.workflowid
from cyto_records r 
  join cyto_record_results rr on r.recordid = rr.recordid
where exists (select *
              from json_array_elements(rr.interval_note) as x(item)
              where x.item ->> 'text' like '%bb%')
```

---

If you are using Postgres 12 or newer, you can use a JSON path expression:

```
select distinct r.workflowid
from cyto_records r 
  join cyto_record_results rr on r.recordid = rr.recordid
where rr.interval_note @@ '$[*].text like_regex "bb"'
```

This assumes that `interval_note` is defined with the recommended type `jsonb`. If it's not, you need to cast it: `interval_note::jsonb`

---

Unrelated to your question, but: the `distinct` operator is not a function.
Enclosing a column after that in parentheses is useless won't change a thing `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

In fact it's an "option" to the SELECT keyword: `SELECT ALL` vs. `SELECT DISTINCT` - similar to `UNION ALL` and `UNION DISTINCT`.

Comment: I'm using Postgresql I'm getting error as "ERROR:  operator does not exist: json @? unknown
LINE 7:                 and rr.interval_note @? '$[*].text like_rege...
                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 193"

Comment: Then you are using something older than Postgres 12. See my edit

Comment: Is this a unique question in 2022?  Ideally, we are trying to get all answers on a given topic in one place.

Comment: @mickmackusa: I am pretty sure this is a duplicate. But SO's search capabilities make it really hard to find such a question. It's actually faster for me to write the answer than to search for a duplicate.

Comment: I'm using Postgres 10.20 version

Comment: ERROR:  function jsonb_array_elements(json) does not exist
LINE 5:               from jsonb_array_elements(rr.interval_note) as...
                           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 151

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: json @@ unknown
LINE 4: where rr.interval_note @@ '$[*].text like_regex "bb"'
                               ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 132

Comment: As I wrote: if your column is not defined with the recommended `jsonb` type but with `json` you need to use `json_array_elements()` with the solution for older Postgres versions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first flatten using lateral join and then perform 'plain' select.
Postgres version before 12:

```sql
select distinct workflowid
from cyto_records r 
  join cyto_record_results rr on (r.recordid = rr.recordid), 
  lateral (select j->>'text' from json_array_elements(rr.interval_note) j) l(txt)
where txt ~ 'bb';
```

Postgres version 12+ using `jsonb_path_query`:

```sql
select distinct workflowid
from from cyto_records r 
  join cyto_record_results rr on (r.recordid = rr.recordid), 
  lateral jsonb_path_query(rr.interval_note, '$[*].text') txt
where txt::text ~ 'bb';
```

Comment: ERROR:  function jsonb_path_query(json, unknown) does not exist
LINE 2: from cyto_record_results t, lateral jsonb_path_query(interva...
                                            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 67

Comment: ERROR:  function jsonb_array_elements(json) does not exist
LINE 2: ...cord_results t, lateral (select j ->> 'text' from jsonb_arra...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 93

Comment: Your Postgres version is older than 12 so  pls. use the first query.

Comment: Then replace `jsonb_array_elements` with `json_array_elements`. Answer updated.